# Run exe from another exe

Tags: c, windows, cmd, cygwin, system

I am trying to write a program that runs an other executable in the same folder with some arguments, this exe is `pdftotext.exe`from poppler-utils and it generates a text file.

I prepare a string to pass it as argument for `system()`, the result string is:

```
cd/D N:\folder0\folder1\folder2\foldern && pdftotext.exe data.pdf -layout -nopgbrk
```

First go to the directory of the file and then run the executable.

When I run it I always get

```
sh: cd/D: No such file or directory
```

but the command works if I run it directly in from the Command Prompt.

I don't think it matters, but this is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function to get the base filename
char *GetFileName(char *path);

int main (void)
{
    // Get path of the acutal file
    char currentPath[MAX_PATH];

    int pathBytes = GetModuleFileName(NULL, currentPath, MAX_PATH);
    if(pathBytes == 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't determine current path\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the current file name
    char* currentFileName = GetFileName(currentPath);

    // prepare string to executable + arguments
    char* pdftotextArg = " && pdftotext.exe data.pdf -layout -nopgbrk";

    // Erase the current filename from the path
    currentPath[strlen(currentPath) - strlen(currentFileName) - 1] = '\0';


    // Prepare the windows command
    char winCommand[500] = "cd/D ";
    strcat(winCommand, currentPath);
    strcat(winCommand, pdftotextArg);

    // Run the command
    system(winCommand);

    // Do stuff with the generated file text

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably want createprocess not system

Comment: @EdHeal, thanks, i tried `createProcess()` but with no luck, i don't understand very well what mean the arguments for that function, specially the last two, any example is welcome.

Comment: Plenty of examples online like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which compiler/environment are you using? Cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`cd` is a "shell" command, not a program that can be executed.</strike>

So to apply it run a shell (`cmd.exe` under windows) and pass the command(s) you want to execute.

Do to so m Make the content of `winCommand` look like this:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd/D N:\folder0\folder1\folder2\foldern && pdftotext.exe data.pdf -layout -nopgbrk"
```

Please note that changing the drive and directory only applies to the environment used by `cmd.exe`. The program's drive and directory stay as they were before the call to `system()`.

---

**Update:**

Looking more closely at the error message one notices the "*`sh: ...`*". This clearly indicates `system()` does not call `cmd.exe`, because it most likley would not prefix an error message like this.

From this fact I dare to conclude the code shown is called in and runs under [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/).

The shell(s) provided and used by Cygwin do not know the windows specific option `/D` to the shell command `cd`, thus the error.

As however the shells used by Cygwin can call `cmd.exe` my orignally provide approach works, although the explaination I gave is wrong, as pointed out by *[pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg)*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366665/run-exe-from-another-exe/31370442?noredirect=1#comment50720288_31370442) below.

Comment: Isn't `system()` supposed to already do that on its own? See [7.22.4.8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.8): *"... the system function passes the string pointed to by string to that command processor to be executed in a manner which the implementation shall document ..."*

Comment: @pmg Hm ... - correct, indeed. However, why this `cd/D: No such file or directory` error then?

Comment: *Cygwin* ... awesome insight :)

Comment: First thanks for your answer, yes i am using clang in cygwin to compile the program, i should have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Your working directory might wrong, and you cannot change it from `cd` command. Since you are using windows, i suggest you using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to execute `pdftotext.exe`, and you can check `CreateProcess`'s `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter if you want set working directory.

Comment: Thanks, i tried but don't understand very well the other arguments, specially the last two, any example is welcome.

Comment: @wallek876 here is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx)